# Шаблон на bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, bootstrap

Можно ли сверстать такой шаблон на bootstrap 3 и если да, то как это сделать?

Страница со всем содержимым фиксированного размера, `header` прикреплен постоянно наверху, левая колонка (сайдбар) — постоянно слева, справа область для текущего контента, при этом, область для контента имеет свой `header`, который также прикреплен.
Если сайдбар имеет слишком много элементов, то у него должен появляться свой скроллбар, то же самое и для области справа. Иными словами, общего скроллбара быть не должно.

Сам я такой шаблон делал, но с использованием JS, в том числе, чтобы отслеживать ресайз окна и пересчитывать размеры.

На картинке изображено то, что хотелось бы получить в итоге.

[image: введите описание изображения здесь]

Comment: Сделать можно всё. А что именно у вас вызвало проблемы в вёрстке, в каком месте вы не смогли реализовать свой макет? В bootstrap 3 такой шаблон делается вообще легко, особенно когда появился border-box :)

Comment: Я пока стандартные шаблоны ковыряю, учусь. Сделать (-переделать/использовать существующий) шаблон с фиксированным  хедером и сайдбаром я могу, но мне непонятно как сделать область справа со своим фиксированным hedaer'ом.

Answer (score 1):

Да, такой вариант возможен.

Если у Вас все хорошо с английским, то лучше ознакомиться с [учебником](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_get_started.asp)

Comment: Спасибо. Вражеский, увы, хромает.

Comment: Посмотрите линк http://habrahabr.ru/post/211032/

Answer (score 0):

Выглядит как типичный dashboard-шаблон; гугл в помощь, ищи "bootstart templates" и вперёд по ссылкам.
Например, [сайт](http://bootstrapzero.com/) - [линк](http://bootstrapzero.com/bootstrap-template/app), [линк](http://bootstrapzero.com/bootstrap-template/responsivedashboard)...

Comment: Искал, скачивал, смотрел. Удовлетворяющих моему желанию нет; а проблема как раз в том, что не понимаю, как хотя бы переделать под себя.

Comment: Шаблон по первому линку на 90% соотв условиям задачи, остальные 10% легко допиливаются руками: ставим position:fixed второму хедеру и margin/padding-top: 40px контейнеру следующему за ним.

Comment: собственно:


    .page-header {
       padding-bottom: 9px;
       margin: 0px 0 20px;
       border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
       position: fixed;
       background-color: #ffffff;
       width: 100%;
    }
    div#main p {
       margin: 60px 0 10px;
    }

Comment: нет, это всё не катит, скроллбар справа остаётся общий, а он должен появляться в том диве, где содержание не помещается, как на рисунке. Да и при подобных решениях ползунок уходит под фиксированный блок сверху, что не эстетично. У меня задуманное решалось с использованием js, похоже и тут без костылей не обойтись.

Answer (score 0):

Зашёл на сайт Bootstrap, полез в [примеры](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/) и нашёл [именно то](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/dashboard/), что вам нужно :)

А чтобы понять как делать фиксированные header у блоков, вот вам [ещё пример](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar-fixed-top/), опять же с офф. сайта